# Does android PageAdapter and ViewPager check for indexoutofbounds exception when using setCurrentItem(int index)?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

So my activity uses the PageAdapter and ViewPager correctly, where 3 images can be scrolled from left to right. So then I have left and right arrows on the activity and I set an onClickListener for both images to scroll left and right with ViewPager pager. The method is like

```
private void setOnClickArrows(final ViewPager pager){
ImageView rightArrow = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.right);
ImageView leftArrow = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.left);


rightArrow.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener () 
                       @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                pager.setCurrentItem(pager.getCurrentItem() + 1);
            }

        });

leftArrow.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener () 
                       @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                pager.setCurrentItem(pager.getCurrentItem() - 1);
            }

        });

}
```

This works perfectly. However, I was wondering how the ViewPager checks if the index is out of bounds and if I should do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it actually does. Refer to the [source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/v4/java/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.java) and have a look at the `setCurrentItemInternal` method (called by `setCurrentItem()`).

There are a few checks in place to avoid a crash, and among one of them is this, which avoids OOBExceptions:

```
if (item < 0) {
   item = 0;
} else if (item >= mAdapter.getCount()) {
   item = mAdapter.getCount() - 1;
}
```

Should you check yourself? Up to you. I wouldn't because those checks are trivial, so I wouldn't expect the checks to disappear.

Comment: Thanks! I checked the docs, but on serCurrentItem() it didn't appear to link farther. Thanks!

Comment: @BoomerTruong You're welcome. Since my answer solved your problem, you should accept it by [clicking the hollowed out checkmark so it turns green.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)